No required SSL certificate was sent
I am getting No required SSL certificate was sent
I am using below code get RestTemplate.
        SSLSocketFactory ssl=this.getKeyStoreFactory();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(requestTimeout);
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(getHttpClient(ssl));
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

Method to get httpclinet.
    private HttpClient getHttpClient(SSLSocketFactory sslContext) {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
                connTtl, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(connPoolMaxSize);
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(connPoolMaxRouteSize);
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(connPoolInvalidateThreshold);
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                .build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        return httpClient;
    }

and getting keystore and Trust Store ,taking location from config
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    try {
        keyStore.load(Files.newInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStorePath).toPath()), keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
        trustStore.load(Files.newInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStorePath).toPath()), keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
    }catch (Exception e){
        error("Exception while createing fsv reset template","FF10",e,null);
    }


    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore,keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TL_SV_1");

    // Initialize our SSL context from the key/trust managers
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();


log.level":"ERROR","error.message":"{"message":"400 Bad Request: \"400 No required SSL certificate was sent400 Bad RequestNo required SSL certificate was sentserver\"","cause":null,"stackTraceElements":

["org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101)","org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:168)","org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)","org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)","org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:825)","org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:783)\

Don't add additional information as comments, edit your question. What you added as comments is totally unreadable. When adding stacktraces to your quesstion please use proper code formatting for this as well.

It sounds very much like the server requires a client certificate and that this is missing in your keystore. Double-check the keys.
